# HYPERLINK function doesn't work inside a user LAMBDA function in the Name Manager

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The following works: `HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com","Google")`, but if I define a user `LAMBDA` function in the *Name Manager* it doesn't work:

```
LINK=LAMBDA(x, HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com",x))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

Is it a bug?, I was not able to find an answer to this and I haven't found such limitation in the [HYPERLINK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/hyperlink-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f) documentation. I would like to use `HYPERLINK` function inside of a user `LAMBDA` function in my real case, this is just a simple sample.

Even the following with no input argument, doesn't work:

```
LINK=LAMBDA(HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com","Google"));
```

On the other hand the following works:

```
=LET(x, "Google", LINK,LAMBDA(x, HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com",x)),LINK(x))
```

[image: output using let]
but I don't want to have a large `LET` function (in my real case) in several places, instead I would like to define something in the *Name Manager*. I am not looking for a VBA approach, just trying to define a user `LAMBDA` function for it.

The closest hypothesis I found is this one: [LAMBDA malfunction with HYPERLINK](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/lambda-malfunction-with-hyperlink/m-p/2960676), but not an official explanation or solution.

Comment: Not sure I understand the emphasis on `LAMBDA` here. Even without `LAMBDA`, hyperlinks defined within Name Manager do not return hyperlinked text when referenced within the worksheet: if *LINK* is defined as the simple `=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com","Google")` then `=LINK` within the worksheet returns the un-hyperlinked "Google".

Comment: Thanks @JosWoolley even for this simple case, it doesn't work, the reason I emphasis on the `LAMBDA` is because in my real case I have a larger function which tries to use `HYPERLINK`. I haven't seen documented why this function doesn't work via *Name Manager*.

Comment: Official MS documentation: "*When you click a cell that contains a HYPERLINK function, Excel jumps to the location listed, or opens the document you specified.*" Via use of a Named Range, technically speaking this violates the condition that the cell contains the `HYPERLINK` function.

Comment: @JosWoolley this explains the behavior when you click on the cell, a cell content can be linked to a name range or even a `LET` function like in my second formula which works. For me this interpretation is forced, knowing already that it doesn't work. The documentation is not clear about this limitation or maybe it is a bug. It looks like there is no workaround. Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand. Your `LET` example refers to a cell which contains the `HYPERLINK` function; your Named Range example refers to a cell which does not contain the `HYPERLINK` function. I see no ambiguity here, nor 'buggy' behaviour.

Comment: @JosWoolley I don't see the difference, both `LINK` functions are the same, just using a different mechanism, both are user `LAMBDA` functions just one defined inside the `LET` function and another one using *Name Manager*. Maybe I am missing something here. Thanks!

Comment: My point was that I was taking the official MS documentation - "*When you click a cell that **contains** a HYPERLINK function...*" - as literal. If the cell instead contains a Defined Name which indirectly refers to that function then I assume that this falls outside of this definition.